# How to restore ubuntu softwares ( including built in)?

Tags: wine, software-center, uninstall, libreoffice, desktop-environments

I had run a command :

```
sudo apt-get remove wine* .
```

Then, all of my Ubuntu softwares had been deleted. Including Terminal, Libreoffice and other built-in sofwares.

Now what should I do to restore all of my previous downloaded software.

Please, help me providing necessary informations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) Reinstall ubuntu-desktop and unity-control-center, this gives you back the built-in software...**

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get --reinstall install unity-control-center
```

**2) Reinstall your lost personal software manually with the Software Center or over the Terminal**

Fortunately, `sudo apt-get remove ...` keeps the configuration files of all removed software on your system. Hence, reinstalling the missing software is the same as restoring it!

**3) Now, if you want, clean-up your system as follows...**

Remove unneeded packages:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Get rid of partial packages:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Get rid of 'orphaned' packages:

```
sudo deborphan | xargs sudo apt-get -y remove --purge
```

Remove configuration files of uninstalled packages:

```
dpkg -l | awk '/^rc/ {print $2}' | xargs sudo dpkg --purge
```

Clean out unused package stuff (cache):

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

**4) Bring your system up-to-date...**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: I want to restore removed software,no manual work.Is there any way?

Comment: You just need to reinstall the missing/removed software. Since you used 'remove' and not 'purge' with yout 'atp-get' command, the configuration files with your personal settings for each program (like chrome) are still around and you don't have to reconfigure anything from scratch - and that is restoring removed software. I'm not sure that there is a way to 'undo' what is removed with 'apt-get'.

Answer (score 1):

You can get back the Ubuntu desktop with

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

From thereon it should be easy to re-install all the other lost packages.

If you're looking for a list of all the (accidentally) uninstalled packages, you can find them in `/var/log/apt/history.log`.

Comment: Suppose , I had installed chrome. But, unfortunately it had removed.Can I re-install removed software without manually?just restore?

Comment: You could theoretically but the effort of automation would be unjustified compared to just finding the relevant section of the Apt log and copying the names of the removed packages to append them to `apt-get install`.